# How to show first property of norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I have a normed space X which is the Space of all real-valued Lipschitz continuous functions on [0,1].
The norm is.
$$ {\lVert x\rVert}_{lip}  =\lvert x(0)\rvert + sup_{s \ne t} \lvert { {x(s) -x(t)} \over {s -t}} \rvert $$
I have a trouble to prove first norm property
$$ {\lVert x\rVert}_{lip} = 0 \iff x = 0 $$
It can be shown that $ x(0) = 0$ easily but How can I show that $ x(s) = 0$ and $x(t) = 0$ iff  $ {\lVert x\rVert}_{lip} = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $||x||_{Lip} = 0$, for every $\epsilon > 0$ it holds
$$\Big| \frac{x(s) - x(t)}{s-t}\Big| < \epsilon$$
for every $s \neq t$. Taking $t = 0$ we get
$|x(s)| < \epsilon |s| \leq \epsilon$
for every $s \in (0,1]$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary $x(s) = 0$ for every $s \in [0,1]$

Comment: Why we took $t = 0$

Comment: @MathStarter To exploit the condition $x(0) = 0$